# Consulta Ajax "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Mi consulta es la siguiente, mi código es:

```
$("#sPedido").change(function(){
    var codigo_c=$("#sPedido").val();


    $.post("traertabla.php",  function(datos){
        $("#midiv").html(datos);
        alert(datos.mensaje);
    });
});
```

La línea:

```
$("#midiv").html(datos);
```

me muestra los datos en pantalla sin ningún problema, el resultado es:

```
{"mensaje":"hola"}
```

Pero, al ejecutar esta linea:

```
alert(datos.mensaje);
```

el alert solo me muestra: `"undefined"`.

¿En qué momento cometí el error?

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que el json que te retorna es un texto debes convertirlo.

```
var datos = $.parseJSON(datos);
```

debería quedar así

```
    $("#sPedido").change(function(){
       var codigo_c=$("#sPedido").val();


       $.post("traertabla.php",  function(datos){
           $("#midiv").html(datos);
           var datosObj = $.parseJSON(datos);
           alert(datosObj.mensaje);
       });
    });
```

Saludos.

Comment: No es bueno ocultar el parámetro con una variable local. Usa un nombre único en su lugar.

Comment: por que no es bueno ?

Comment: La ocultación de variables trae algunos problemas, como por ejemplo, pensar que se usa la variable de más alto nivel cuando se usa la local; en asuntos financieros esto puede tener consecuencias desastrozas. En funciones, los parámetros ya son variables locales, por lo que prácticamente se está **sobreescribiendo** el parámetro haciendo que este ya no esté disponible en su forma inicial.

Comment: Es verdad pero en este caso la variable no pierde su información solo se hace "trabajable" ¿o de todas formas no se debe hacer?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, si, al parecer, la forma en que tu propones es la correcta, pero aun no me funciona, me sigue mostrando los datos en el "div" pero ahora no me aparece el alert, que podria ser? gracias!

Comment: Te lanza algún error?

Comment: No me carga nada, nisiquiera en el div, en la consola sale : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Cuando le agrego esto : var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(datos)); . En la consola me muestra : "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience".

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que comentas lo que quieres hacer es mandar una valor por medio de una función relizar una consulta a otro archivo y que te regrese un valor, podrias usar lo siguiente.

```
$(function(){
 $("#enviar").click(function(){
  var url = "consulta.php"; 
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $("#valor").serialize(), 
     success: function(data)
       {
          $("#respuesta").html(data); 
         }
        });

      return false; 
  });
});

<div id="respuesta"></div>
```

dentro del `div` recibes la respuesta de la función.

Comment: El código del OP está bien ha no ser por un pequeño detalle: no está parseando a JSON el string que devuelve la petición. Tu has hecho lo mismo que el pero usando `$.ajax` en lugar del atajo.

Comment: cierto Gustavo, es basicamente lo mismo, con respecto al parsear el JSON como me recomendaron en la otra respuesta, lo intenté pero ahora no me muestra el alert, que podria ser?